# How should I work in a Laravel project under git, and at the same time in a Laravel component in a component/ folder in the same laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, git

I have a main project using laravel framework under `git`.

Now, I have to code a component that must have his own git repository, but I need to code it into `/component/mycomponent` in my Laravel project.

My issue is that if I specify a new origin for my component, it will also set it for main project. How should I do ?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: A little more "PHP" way as using git submodules, which kerbh0lz suggested.

Create a new repository for the component and require it by composer in the main project.

If you really need a physical class / file in /component/mycomponent just put a class in there which extends from the one in vendor.